# How to connect UrbanCode with Changeman for mainframe code build?

Tags: cobol, mainframe, urbancode, serena

I want to build mainframe code kept in Changeman through UrbanCode deploy. Is there any plugins/connectivity mechanism with changeman?

Answer (score 1):

ChangeMan is not a repository, it is a build tool and version control manager. The source code is kept in one or more of {PDS, PDSE, z/Unix files}  It may help to think of ChangeMan as analogous to GNU make in this context.

I suggest starting with the [ChangeMan ZMF documentation](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/changeman-zmf/).  Select the link for your version and release of ChangeMan ZMF and take a look at Chapter 1 of the User's Guide if you're unfamiliar with ChangeMan - it will help to familiarize you with the terminology in the documentation you *really* want.

Then look at the ZMF XML Services Users Guide and/or the ZMF Web Services Getting Started Guide.

Be sure to talk to your ChangeMan Administrator(s).  Some of what you want to do may require work on their part.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to build using IBM Dependency Based Build, and then deploy the compiled artifacts from Urbancode. You can replace Changeman entirely this way, using a modern SCM such a Git or GitHub as the SCM repository:
https://www.strongback.us/2019/09/understanding-how-github-fits-in-a-mainframe-devops-toolchain